# DB2 Primary-key truncation bug?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

So I've searched around quite a bit and cannot seem to find an answer to this. I have two different applications that speak to the same DB2 database; one uses Hibernate, and the other uses just the native ResultSet, PreparedStatement, etc.

Let's say for example I have an object who's primary key is "ABC". The database has this keys length defined as 3. If I use the spring repositories findOne("ABC"), it returns my object. But the strange thing is if I call findOne("ABC123456"), it will still return that same database row, except the key field in the object is "ABC123456".

Now if I run a native query on the other application using a PreparedStatement, the same thing will happen, except in this case the primary key is returned correctly in the ResultSet.

Assuming this is a DB issue, but not sure what to look at. The database column is setup as a CHAR(3).

Comment: what platform and version of Db2?

Comment: And what character set and what collating sequence? And ideally the table and index definitions. Have you tried pure SQL directly against the database?